# Auto Play isn't working for swf flash video (weather app)

Tags: html, flash

I may be missing something but I am trying to embed a weather app I found into my website. I am using this as my HTML code:

```
<div style="width:800px; height:250px;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf&autostart=true" width="800" height="250">
    <param name="movie" value="http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf&autoStart=true"/>
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <param name="autoPlay" value="true"/>
    <param name="flashvars" 

    value="location_id=gn:5007804&amp;location_name=Royal%20Oak&amp;time_format=12&amp;unit_system=us&amp;background=#FFFFFF&amp;mini_temperature=true&amp;mini_time=true&amp;mini_locationBar=true&amp;mini_action=full_screen&amp;copyright_bar=false;&autostart=true;"
/>


</object>
</div>
```

Notice how I put the param name = "Autoplay" value="true" line as well as trying to put it in the URL. Am I missing something here?

If I just paste the URL http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf into a webbrowser, it auto plays no problem so it must be one of the parameters I have entered wrong.

I have looked many times on StackOverflow for a solution and have entered autoPlay="true" in many spots without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your shown code and it's working fine (Chrome browser on Windows). Maybe you need to clear browser history & clear any cached files?

It only shows a "click to play" icon if the display width is smaller than 600px. Did you ever have such a smaller setting that is being cached & re-used?

Also regarding `data="http://swf.yowindow.com/yowidget3.swf&autostart=true"` the `&autostart=true` is not needed. Please remove it & test again (resave as  different `filename.html` if needed).